# Phpspreadsheet Import issue Memory limit exhausted (tried to allocate 20971520 bytes

Tags: phpspreadsheet

Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20971520 bytes) in /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Collection/Memory.php on line 66

Answer (score 3):

I believe this question has been asked several times on StackOverflow before. I have been trawling through the internet trying to find a solution for this too.

Most of the solutions I found suggested that you change the memory_limit within your php.ini file. This doesn't really solve the problem, it simply allows PHP to consume more of your servers memory. Depending on how much data you are trying to read, you may find that you don't hit the memory limit, but instead the script takes a considerable amount of time to run. If this is the case, you will have to change the max_execution_time within your php.ini, and deal with the long execution time.

If you want to both reduce the memory consumption and the execution time, the solution will depend on exactly what you are trying to do. Below I have listed some things to consider.

You can decrease the memory consumption and execution time in Phpspreadsheet using the below settings.

```
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

Note that this will mean all color/styling information will not be accessible.

```
$reader->setReadEmptyCells(false);
```

Note that this will exclude empty cells.

These two settings significantly improved the memory consumption and execution time in my case as the spreadsheet I was reading had styling applied to all cells.

If the spreadsheet you are reading has multiple worksheets and you are only interested in reading one of them, you can also save some memory and time with:

```
$reader->setLoadSheetsOnly('SheetName');
```

If after applying these settings your script is still not performing as desired, you may have to consider switching libraries.

[Spout](https://github.com/box/spout) is a more efficient library which uses way less memory. The only downside is that it does not support XLS files.

Comment: `$reader->setReadEmptyCells(false);` for the win!  So much better advice than upping the memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, make the following changes:

1. Use a stream reader: Instead of loading the entire spreadsheet into memory, a stream reader is used to read the data. This helps reduce memory usage.
2. Set the setReadDataOnly flag: By setting the setReadDataOnly flag to true, only cell values are read, which further reduces memory consumption.

> ```
> $reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
>
> $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);    
>
> $spreadsheet = $reader->load($excelFilePath);
> ```

3. Increase memory limit: The memory limit is set to -1, which means no specific limit is imposed. However, you may adjust this value according to your server's memory capacity if necessary.

> `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`

Comment: did you use chatgpt at all to write any part of this answer?

Comment: @starball I faced a similar problem and solved it by researching. This answer is provided to contribute helpful information and to encourage collaborative problem-solving.